# Why does my Latex want multiple \end(document)s?

Tags: errors, pdftex

My Latex document wants multiple instances of `\end{document}` even though I only have one `begin{document}`.

Without the extra `\end{document}`s, I get the error:

```
Compile Error. Sorry your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason.
```

With a list of non-fatal errors (I haven't uploaded some photos yet), and the fatal error:

```
Emergency Stop.

<*> main.tex

***(job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

And it didn't disappear until I added an extra `\end(doument)` at the end of the document. After a while the error re-appeared, again with no apparent fix until I added yet another `\end(doument)`.

**I now have three instances of `\end(doument)` with only one `\begin(document)`, but it seems to have fixed the error for now.**

**Possible reasons (maybe):**

The error started appearing a while after I added the `etex` package, so it might be something to do with that. I added this package because I had reached the picture limit. Although, it did compile a few times without any problem after I added this package, so it may not be that.

I am also using the subfiles package, and each section is in its own tex file. These are added to the main tex file with `\subfile{path}`. these sub files have no pre-amble as the `\subfile` command works just like the text in the .tex file is simply copied and pasted into the location of `\subfile{path}`. Again, this was working long before the error appeared, but the document is getting large now so maybe its confusing things?

I only use the `\input{}` command once, at the very start of the `main.tex` file, before `\begin{document}`. This is to input all of the preamble stuff, such as user packages and custom commands. Once again, this was working long before the error.

The start of my `main.tex` file looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

    \input{header.tex}

\title{the title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
```

The header.tex file is just a list of `\usepackage` and `\definecolor`, `\newcommand` and `\linespread{1.5}` commands. Nothing else. There is nothing at the bottom or start of this file. Again, this was working fine long before the error started appearing. I just thought I'd mention it so you get an idea of the structure of my source code.

I am writing this project on the ShareLatex website, with the pdfLaTeX compiler. My document is 200 pages long. I have over 20 used packages. If you want to see the full header file I've put it in a separate project viewable [here.](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/new/template?zipUrl=%2Ftemplates%2F557d95e25c73ff874a3e2d8d%2Fv%2F0%2Fzip&templateName=my%20packages&compiler=pdflatex)

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have `MultiEndDocumentTeX` installed ;-) No, joking. This seems to be an error

Comment: Do you also get a \begin{something} ended with \end{document} error?  Also, try \fi\end{document}

Comment: Nope. I have a few `Bad math`, `Missing $`, `inputenc Errorunicode char`, `Missing }`, `Misplaced alignment tab`, and `Missing file` (for the missing pictures) errors. But all of these are non fatal, and are there regardless with I have the extra `\end{document}`s  or not. The extra `\end{document}`s just get rid of the fatal error.

Comment: Adding `\fi\end{document}`  insread of my three `\end{document}`s. gives an `extra \fi` error.

Comment: if you want someone to debug your code, it helps if you show the code. Make a small test document where each file is only a few lines long that reproduces this error and post into your question. (that;s rather more helpful, and permanent) than an off site link to a full project.

Comment: Hi David. My source is huge, and I cannot reproduce the error in a small document as the error should theoretically not exist. The link I provided is just a list of packages I have used, in case it is conflicting packages that have caused this error. I posted this question in the hope that someone has had a similar error before, or if someone could advice me of the type of thing that could cause this type of error.

Comment: have you possibly added a package that defines a comment environment?  an `\end{document}` buried inside a comment block could hide it.

Comment: @barbara I've not. I have no packages that are associated with comments. All my comments are using the original % method.

Comment: Start by fixing the `Bad math`, `Missing $`, `Missing }`, and `Misplaced alignment tab` errors.  They cause TeX to insert various things in your file to try and survive.  I expect that your issue with `\end{document}` will disappear.  Also, make a copy of your project, and start removing stuff from it to make a small file/set of files showing the error.  This is always possible.

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly caused by some environment not being closed properly. This could be because you have forgotten to close one or it could be a missing bracket or the missing dollar signs you mention. With certainty your problem is NOT that LaTeX requires more than one `\end{document}`. With equal certainty we can't help you find you error without seeing your code. Try commenting out the document little by little, or adding `\end{document}`'s if you like, to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: I've fixed all of the other errors. The only error now is the Emergency Stop error described in the original question. And it is still only fixed by multiple `\end{documents}` :( . I might have a go at adding the subfiles in one by one, but we have 73 sub files, and the document takes about 2 mins to compile each time. The project is due tomorrow, and as it works this isn't a priority at the moment. I asked just in case the problem got worse.